# How can I upgrade a complete list of packages from stable to backports

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, aptitude, backports

I have installed Qt 4.8.2 from Debian Wheezy on my system. Now, some application requires Qt 4.8.3 on my machine, so I looked at the versions and found that Qt 4.8.6 is avaliable in Wheezy-Backports:

```
# aptitude versions qt4-qmake:amd64
Paket qt4-qmake:                                                         
i A 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11             stable              900
p A 4:4.8.6+dfsg-2~bpo70+1      wheezy-backports    800
```

I tried to upgrade the package `qt4-qmake` and hope that it will upgrade all other required packages via dependencies, but I get the following:

```
# aptitude install qt4-qmake:amd64/wheezy-backports
The following packages will be REMOVED:           
  qt4-qmake{u} 
0 packages updated, 0 additionaly installed, 1 will be removed and 0 not updated.
0 B of archives must be downloaded. After unpacking 5.030 kB will be free.
The following packages have broken dependencies:
 libqt4-dev : Requires: qt4-qmake (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11) But it shouldn't be installed.
The following actions will resolve the dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:             
1)      automoc                                       
2)      kdelibs5-dev                                  
3)      liblastfm-dev                                 
4)      libphonon-dev                                 
5)      libqca2-dev                                   
6)      libqt4-dev                                    
7)      libqt4-opengl-dev                             
8)      libqtwebkit-dev                               
9)      libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev                          
10)     libstrigiqtdbusclient-dev                     

      Leave the following dependencies broken:
11)     qt4-designer suggests libqt4-dev             
12)     qt4-dev-tools suggests libqt4-dev            


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

The output was translated from German, so it isn't aptitude's original output

After entering `n`, it goes along with removing packages, but it doesn't suggest any other updates.

Is there any way to make aptitude to update all the packages? Adding an `libgt4-dev/wheezy-backports` also doesn't help since this requires other packages to be upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With apt-get you do

```
apt-get install -t wheezy-backports qt4-qmake
```

I don't think the `:amd64` is necessary, unless amd64 is not the standard arch for your machine. A similar syntax should work with aptitude in theory, i.e.

```
aptitude install -t wheezy-backports qt4-qmake
```

However, aptitude is inclined to be a bit wacky; I'm not a big fan of it. I'd use apt-get if I were you. The `/wheezy-backports` syntax is intended to make only the package marked like that installable. For backports you usually want `-t wheezy-backports` or similar (insert correct name of release).

Incidentally, you can get output in English.
See e.g. [Switch terminal output language from native language to english](https://askubuntu.com/q/264283/). Eric's answer will work, I think.

Comment: I added the `:amd64` only because I get results to install the `i386` package instead, but `:amd64` only moves this result more to the back (I need to enter more n until I see it). And why does the command install qt5?

Comment: @msrd0 I'm sorry. I have no idea what either part of your comment means. Did you try the command I suggested? Did it work for you? If not, please post what errors you get.

Comment: I tried your command for apt-get, and it says that it will update the packages, but also install qt5 and a whole bunch of other packages that I don't want/need

Comment: This command does indeed want to install a slew of packages, but qt5 is not among them, at least on my system. can you paste the command output for your system in your question, please?

Comment: I have now installed all the packages, but here is the output (translated the important part): http://paste.debian.net/129714/

Comment: @msrd0 Paste in the question, please. And did you see my comment about getting output in English?